# Changing partition dev path

Tags: partition, gpt

I have a UEFI system that I installed Arch Linux on beside Windows, then later removed Windows and made it Linux only, keeping the EFI boot partition of course. After removing all Windows and recovery partitions, my Linux root partition was still identified as `/dev/sda5`.

lsblk output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   260M  0 part /boot
└─sda5   8:5    0 931.3G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Now I'd like to install btrfs, but I want my partitions to be ordered and have concurrent names to avoid confusion, i.e. boot=`/dev/sda1`, linux root=`/dev/sda2`, and btrfs=`/dev/sda3`. From poking around in gparted, I can't seem to find any functionality for this.

I've tried googling this for quite some time and either I'm not sure how to phrase it properly, or people ambiguously use "name" to mean "label" when discussing partitions. Is this possible to accomplish without backing up, formatting my drive, and starting fresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `fdisk`. Carefully note the characteristics of the existing partition (position, size, type, name, UUID if you care). Delete it, then create a new one with the desired number and the same characteristics.

This is a lot of risk for a negligible benefit, so I don't recommend doing it. Partition numbers are pretty arbitrary, they can't always be chosen freely (with MBR partitions, a primary or extended partition has to be in the range 1–4 and a logical partition has to be ≥5). You should avoid using partition numbers anywhere and use UUIDs, GPT names, or better LVM volume names or filesystem labels instead.